# How to make http request in Apigee JavaScript policy?

Tags: apigee

I am using Apigee API proxy and in the PreFlow part of the Proxy endpoint I have to make a http request. I created a JavaScript policy, where I tried using `fetch` to make the request, but when I call the endpoint, the response is `ReferenceError: "fetch" is not defined`. Does anybody have any suggestions what could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apigee JavaScript Object Model exposes `httpClient` object.

More detail can be found in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/reference/javascript-object-model#makingjavascriptcalloutswithhttpclient) .

Answer (score 0):

I set a Variable to be called later and used the httpClient call like so:

```
//===================================
//== Set Function to pass response ==
//===================================

function onComplete (response, error){
         
  //== Check if HTTP request was successful ==
  //==========================================

if(response){
  context.setVariable("responsePayload1", response.content);
}
     
  //== Set Error Variable is it fails ==
  //====================================

else {
  context.setVariable("example.error", "Whoops: "+error)
}}    
        
//==================================
//== Set Variable to run function ==
//==================================

var calloutResponse = httpClient.get("http://yourwebsitename.com/your-call-uri", onComplete);
```

By setting the variable it forces the JS to run the httpClient.get command in addition to running the above function.